# Integrate Amazon S3 into OSGi (Apache Felix)

Tags: maven, amazon-s3, osgi, aws-sdk, apache-felix

I try to add "Upload to amazon S3" functionality to my bundle. I added dependency on aws-java-sdk to bundle's pom:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
<version>1.11.93</version>
</dependency>
```

After that, I edited configuration of maven-bundle-plugin:

```
<Embed-Dependency>
 im4java;scope=compile,aws-java-sdk;scope=compile|runtime;optional=false;inline=true
</Embed-Dependency>
<Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
```

But when I try to install bundle I get error message

> missing requirement [447.74] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (osgi.wiring.package=com.amazonaws.auth

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you looked inside your bundle? What's embedded? What is been generated in the MANIFEST.MF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this package to

```
<Export-Package>
```

or to

```
<Private-Package>
```

In later case be sure to add all other packages, cause adding of

```
<Private-Package>
```

will override default behavior. In simplest case it should looks like

```
<Private-Package>com.amazonaws.*, *</Private-Package>
```